# DFT of signal with mod

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

My question is about a real signal : $x[n]$ ,$n=0....N-1$
and DFT $X[k]$ also with $N$ length.
I know that $X[k]=$$X[((-k))_N]$  and
$x[n]$=$x[((-n))_N] $.
now, there is a signal :
$y[n]$=$x[((n-1))_{N/2}]$.
Im asking for matrix $A$ that $Y=AX$ , while $Y$ is $Y[k]$ vect and  $X$ is $X[k]$ vect.
first,I tried to find the DFT by definition:
$Y[k]=$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[((n-1))_{N/2}] e^{\frac{-j2\pi kn}{N}}$ .
I tried to find a matrix but I dont know how to continue from this point.

- $[((n ))_N]$ means $n $ modulo N

  Thanks for help

Comment: I don't understand your notations. What do you mean with $x[k]=x[((-k))_N] $ ? What is $y$, and $Y$ is its DFT ?

Comment: $x[k]$ its the DFT of x [n] and this is the information that I have about this signal . $x ((-k))_N$ means mod N. And Y its the DFT of y

Comment: So you meant $X[k]$ is the DFT of $x[n]$.. And what is mod $N$ ??

Comment: Mod means Modulo operation

Comment: You apply it to what ?.. In other words, how do you define $x[n],y[n],X[k],Y[k]$..

Comment: x[n],y[n] thats a real signal and X[k],Y[k] is the DFT of each one

Comment: ... How do you define $y[n]$ in term of $x[n]$

Comment: It is written in the question that y [n]=X [n-1 modulo N/2]

Comment: Please put some more effort into formulating and formatting your question. I cannot make sense of it as it is currently written.

Comment: $y[n] = x[n-1 \mod N/2]$ is written nowhere. Also $x[n-1 \mod N/2]$ doesn't make any sense if $x[n] \ne x[n+N/2]$. The matrix sending $x[n]$ to $x[n-1]$ is of course $M_{i,j+1} = 1, M_{i,j} =0$ otherwise.